# Permutations of $[n]$ where no 3 numbers congruent $\mod k$ are consecutive

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

### Question:

> Given natural numbers $k$ and $n$, in how many ways can we order the numbers $1,2,\dots, n$ such that no three consecutive numbers are congruent $\mod k$?

I was reading [this paper](https://math.osu.edu/sites/default/files/perfect%20shuffle.pdf) where the problem for no adjacent pairs is solved and wondered can we use those methods also for triples (or even more generally forbidding $r$ consecutive congruent numbers).

---

**My thoughts:**

If $n=qk+r$ where $r\in \{0,\dots, k-1\}$ (i.e $q = \left\lfloor \frac{n}{k} \right\rfloor$ and $r= n \mod k$), I think the answer is given by

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-t}p_{ q }(t)^{k-r}p_ {q+1}(t)^{r} dt$$

where $p_m(z)$ is the polynomial

$$p_m(z) = \sum_{A \subset C \text{ compatible}} (-1)^{|A|} z^{m-\rho(A)}$$

where $C$ is the set of all triples of distinct numbers from $[m]$. A triple $(i_1, i_2, i_3)$ corresponds to the constraints that in (the one line notation of) a permutation the number $i_1$ is followed by $i_2$ and $i_2$ is followed by $i_3$. Compatibility means there is some permutation satisfying all constraints of $A$. So this is just like in the paper but now we have triples instead of pairs. The function $\rho$ checks when we glue the constraints in $A$ together, how many items are left to permute (or $m$ minus that).

I have managed to compute the polynomials $p_m$ up to $m=13$ (starting from $m=0$):

```
    1,
    z,
    z^2,
    z^3 - 6*z,
    z^4 - 24*z^2 + 24*z,
    z^5 - 60*z^3 + 120*z^2,
    z^6 - 120*z^4 + 360*z^3 + 360*z^2 - 720*z,
    z^7 - 210*z^5 + 840*z^4 + 2520*z^3 - 10080*z^2 + 5040*z,
    z^8 - 336*z^6 + 1680*z^5 + 10080*z^4 - 60480*z^3 + 60480*z^2,
    z^9 - 504*z^7 + 3024*z^6 + 30240*z^5 - 241920*z^4 + 302400*z^3 + 362880*z^2 - 362880*z,
    z^10 - 720*z^8 + 5040*z^7 + 75600*z^6 - 756000*z^5 + 907200*z^4 + 5443200*z^3 - 10886400*z^2 + 3628800*z,
    z^11 - 990*z^9 + 7920*z^8 + 166320*z^7 - 1995840*z^6 + 1663200*z^5 + 39916800*z^4 - 119750400*z^3 + 79833600*z^2,
    z^12 - 1320*z^10 + 11880*z^9 + 332640*z^8 - 4656960*z^7 + 665280*z^6 + 199584000*z^5 - 778377600*z^4 + 558835200*z^3 + 718502400*z^2 - 479001600*z,
    z^13 - 1716*z^11 + 17160*z^10 + 617760*z^9 - 9884160*z^8 - 8648640*z^7 + 778377600*z^6 - 3632428800*z^5 + 1037836800*z^4 + 18681062400*z^3 - 24908083200*z^2 + 6227020800*z
```

The leading term is always $z^m$ (coming from the empty set). Second term is $-m(m-1)(m-2)z^{m-2}$ (coming from all the singletons). It appears that the last term is $m!z^l$ where $l$ is either $1$ or $2$ and that cycles with $m$, every third being $l=2$ and others $l=1$ (except $m=0$). Also, it seemed up to $m=12$, that the signs go like +0-++-++-... but in $m=13$ that is broken (assuming I have the correct polynomials).

I did the calculation like this: consider what sort of blocks are formed when we do "the gluing" of $A$. This is a partition of $m$ into parts of size at least $3$ and into $1$'s, which are the numbers left over (the ones not in any triple of $A$).
Then consider how many triples go into each part to form it. Now we have to count how many ways the triples can lie in that block. This is given by a binomial coefficient, since each triple can overlap the previous by $1$ or $2$ places and in order to have a block of size $L$, we choose $L-J-2$ out of the $J$ triples we put to have overlap $1$ (so they increase the length by $2$).
Then, the actual numbers to the triples are given by a partial permutation of the $m$ numbers (leaving out the $1$-blocks).

But counting this way, there are symmetries that lead to overcounting. For example if there are two blocks of same size to which we put the same amount of triples, those get counted twice, so we have to divide by $2$. Or more generally $K$ similar blocks, divide by $K!$. But also for example for $m=10$, the blocks $[5, 5]$ putting $[2, 3]$ and putting $[3, 2]$ are symmetric. Those I fixed manually afterwords, because I don't understand how to do it programmatically. But I can add the code I used (SageMath) to do these calculations if someone is interested.

I'm not entirely sure all my $p_m$'s are correct (up to $m=6$ should be, since those can be done on paper). But at least they give correct result for small test cases. Also for $k=2,3$ and $n$ a multiple of $k$ I found these OEIS sequences: [A177790](https://oeis.org/A177790) and [A247150](https://oeis.org/A247150) (you multiply by $(\frac{n}{k}!)^{k}$ to account for the permutations among the congruent numbers).